# How to use drill down functionality using pop up window in ASP.Net (Fusion Charts)

Tags: asp.net, fusioncharts

I am using a drill down functionality where i can click the bar chart and it will open new page with the new child chart.  But i what i don't want is to open a new window, all what i want is to use a pop up window with the child chart in it.  I have seen some example from fusion-chart website but they are using xml format and i cannot follow their example.  Here is my entire code which is working fine but the only thing i need to change instead of opening a new page; i just need to use a pop up window.  How can i do that?  pls help and thanks for your time..
here is my main page code:

```
//aspx code
    <asp:Literal ID="chart_from_db" runat="server">        
            </asp:Literal>
 //code behind   
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);        
            StringBuilder xmlStr = new StringBuilder();      
            xmlStr.Append("<chart caption='Total Revenue' palette='3' showValues='0' numberPrefix='$' useRoundEdges='1'>");
            {

                string sqlStatement = "SELECT Category, AvgNumbers FROM Table1";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {             
                    xmlStr.AppendFormat("<set label='{0}' value='{1}' link='{2}'/>", reader["Category"].ToString(), reader["AvgNumbers"].ToString(), Server.UrlEncode("DrillDown1.aspx?AvgDays=" + reader["Category"].ToString()));
                }            
                xmlStr.Append("</chart>");           
                reader.Close();
                con.Close();            
                FusionCharts.SetRenderer("javascript");
                chart_from_db.Text = FusionCharts.RenderChart(
                    "FusionChartsXT/Column3D.swf", // Path to chart's SWF
                    "", // Page which returns chart data. Leave blank when using Data String.
                    xmlStr.ToString(), // String containing the chart data. Leave blank when using Data URL.
                    "annual_revenue",   // Unique chart ID
                    "640", "340",       // Width & Height of chart
                    false,              // Disable Debug Mode
                    true);              // Register with JavaScript object
            }
```

And here is child page that opens up when the chart is clicked.

```
// ASPX code
    <div>
    <asp:Literal ID="MyChart" runat="server">        
            </asp:Literal>
//code benind    
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            String AvgDays = Request.QueryString["AvgDays"];
            StringBuilder xmlStr = new StringBuilder();
            xmlStr.Append("<chart caption='Total Revenue' palette='3' showValues='0' numberPrefix='$' useRoundEdges='1'>");

            {

                string sqlStatement = "select MonthYear, AvgNumbers from Table2 where AvgDays= '" + AvgDays.ToString() + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();            
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Construct the chart data in XML format
                    xmlStr.AppendFormat("<set label='{0}' value='{1}' link='{1}'/>", reader["MonthYear"].ToString(), reader["AvgNumbers"].ToString());
                }

                // End the XML string
                xmlStr.Append("</chart>");

                // Close the result set Reader object and the Connection object
                reader.Close();
                con.Close();

                // Set the rendering mode to JavaScript, from the default Flash.
                FusionCharts.SetRenderer("javascript");

                // Call the RenderChart method, pass the correct parameters, and write the return value to the Literal tag
                MyChart.Text = FusionCharts.RenderChart(
                    "FusionChartsXT/Column3D.swf", // Path to chart's SWF
                    "", // Page which returns chart data. Leave blank when using Data String.
                    xmlStr.ToString(), // String containing the chart data. Leave blank when using Data URL.
                    "crab",   // Unique chart ID
                    "640", "340",       // Width & Height of chart
                    false,              // Disable Debug Mode
                    true);              // Register with JavaScript object
            }
```

Comment: can anyone help here?? thanks

Comment: Use `p-` prefix as per http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/DrillDown/PopUps.html

Answer (score 0):

please refer the link below.,.
http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/JavaScript/JS_LinkedCharts.html

-LinkedCharts in ExtJS window 
-Opening LinkedCharts in jQuery PrettyPhoto 
-Opening LinkedCharts in jQuery dialog

I hope... this may help you!

Answer (score 0):

In a pop-up window -

When defining the link attribute, precede the target URL with P- to open the link in a popup window.
To know more about it use the [link](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/drill-down#in-a-pop-up-window)

```
    const dataSource = {
   "chart": {
        "caption": "Juice Flavors",
        "subCaption": "Last year",
        "xAxisName": "Flavor",
        "yAxisName": "Amount (In USD)",
        "numberPrefix": "$",
        "placevaluesInside": "1",
        "theme": "fusion",
        "rotateValues": "0"
      },
  "data": [{
        "label": "Apple",
        "value": "810000",
        "link": "P-detailsWin,width=400,height=300,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes, resizable=no-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple"
    },
    {
        "label": "Cranberry",
        "value": "620000",
        "link": "P-detailsWin,width=400,height=300,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes, resizable=no-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry"
    },
    {
        "label": "Grapes",
        "value": "350000",
        "link": "P-detailsWin,width=400,height=300,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes, resizable=no-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grape"
    }]
    
  
};

         FusionCharts.ready(function() {
            const myChart = new FusionCharts({
               type: "bar2d",
               renderAt: "chart-container",
               width: "100%",
               height: "500",
               dataFormat: "json",
               dataSource:dataSource
            });
            
            
            myChart.render();
         });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xsm95o2p/1/)